# C# Down casting Issue

Tags: c#, oop

I have a Face class which derives from an Equipment base class.In the base class(Equpiment),there is a method that populates and returns an Equipment Object based on its rowID in a database.

In the Derived clasd (FaceClass),I call the super

```
public PPE_EquipmentClass GetEquipmentByRowID(Int32 rowID)
    {
        PPE_EquipmentClass Equipment = new PPE_EquipmentClass();  
        returns Equipment; 
    }
```

In the derived class :

```
 public class PPE_Face : PPE_EquipmentClass
    {

     public PPE_Face GetFaceData(Int32 rowID)
    {
         if (rowID>0)
        {
            try
            {  
               PPE_Face Face = null;
               Face = new PPE_Face();
               PPE_EquipmentClass _ppeEquip = new PPE_EquipmentClass();
               _Face =(PPE_Face) _ppeEquip.GetEquipmentByRowID(rowID);
                               }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }


   }
```

But I keep getting

> "Unable to cast object of type 'PPEWebApp.Classes.PPE_EquipmentClass'
>   to type 'PPEWebApp.Classes.PPE_Face"

I'm not really sure why the down casting is not working,even though Equipment is the base class.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Is this code snippet incomplete? where is _Face declared?

Comment: Am I reading this wrong ... it looks like you aren't downcasting - you are upcasting... which doesn't make sense? e.g.  `_Face = (PPE_Face) _ppeEquip.GetEquipmentByRowID(rowID);` you can't cast a less derived type to a more derived type.

Comment: I'm guessing `returns` is just a typo, otherwise this would not compile.

Comment: @Charleh I think that technically this is Downcasting, what's being missed by the OP is that while Upcasting is legal in C#, Downcasting is generally *illegal* without some special conversion mechanism.

Comment: @Napstar. Say you have an animal, what gives you reason to believe you can cast that animal to a pig? What if that animal is actually your dog? Think the pig cast is going to work?

Answer (score 1):

you instantiate it as a PPE_EquipmentClass rather than a PPE_Face class:

```
public PPE_EquipmentClass GetEquipmentByRowID(Int32 rowID)
{
    PPE_EquipmentClass Equipment = new PPE_EquipmentClass();  
    return Equipment; 
}
```

If you want it to be a PPE_Face you have to instantiate it as such. Being a member of the parent class doesn't necessarily mean you are a member of the child class, in this case you obviously aren't as it is instantiated as a new PPE_EquipmentClass().  You could write this:

```
public PPE_EquipmentClass GetEquipmentByRowID(Int32 rowID)
{
    PPE_EquipmentClass Equipment = new PPE_Face();  
    return Equipment; 
}
```

but it is unclear if this is what you actually want.

Comment: My intention in writing is that way is because, there are several types of equipment, and instead writing a getEquipment for each one, They all use the base's class's own. The return value is then cast into what erver type of derived equipment.

Comment: @Napstar Well in this case you are casting something that is instantiated as a Equipment as a Face which is illegal.  You can't instantiate something as a parent class than expect to always be able to cast it to the child class, you can only do the opposite.